# Multiple sliders on one page jssor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jssor

Hello I have problem with multiple sliders in one page.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="slider0" class="slider-left" style="width:700px;">
                <!-- Loading Screen -->
                 <div u="slides" class="slides2" style="width:700px;">
                    <div  data-id="0">
                        <img u="image"  src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pixel.gif' class="img-wrap" data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/1.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <article class="description">
                            <div class="row animate titles">
                                <div class="col-md-3 leftBar">
                                    <h3 class="title">Opis</h3>
                                    <p class="year">2014</p>


                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row animate">
                                <div class="col-md-9 leftBar">
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Lokalizacja: asda</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Powieszchnia zabudowy: <span class="small">400 m2</span></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Powieszchnia użytkowa: <span class="small">400 m2</span></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Ilość kondygnacji: Podziemna: 0 // Nadziemna: 1</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Wizualizacje: Nubo</h4>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>

                            </div>

                          </article>
                    </div>
                    <div  data-id="2">
                        <img  u="image"  src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pixel.gif' class="img-wrap" data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/a2.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div  data-id="3">
                        <img  u="image" src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pixel.gif' class="img-wrap" data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/a2.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>


                <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora13l" style="top: 123px; left: 0px;">
                </span>
                <!-- Arrow Right -->
                <span u="arrowright" class="jssora13r" style="top: 123px; right: 5px;">
                </span>
            </div>

            <div id="slider1" class="slider slider-left" style="width:700px;">
                <!-- Loading Screen -->
                 <div u="slides" class="slides2" style="width:700px;">
                    <div data-id="0">
                        <img u="image"   src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pixel.gif' class="img-wrap"data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/a5.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div data-id="1">
                        <article class="description">
                            <div class="row animate titles">
                                <div class="col-md-3 leftBar">
                                    <h3 class="title">Opis</h3>
                                    <p class="year">2014</p>


                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row animate">
                                <div class="col-md-9 leftBar">
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Lokalizacja: asda</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Powieszchnia zabudowy: <span class="small">400 m2</span></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Powieszchnia użytkowa: <span class="small">400 m2</span></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Ilość kondygnacji: Podziemna: 0 // Nadziemna: 1</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box">
                                        <h4>Wizualizacje: Nubo</h4>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>

                            </div>

                          </article>
                    </div>
                    <div data-id="2">
                        <img  u="image" class="img-wrap"  src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pixel.gif' data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/a2.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div data-id="3">
                        <img  u="image" class="img-wrap"  src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pixel.gif' data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/a3.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>


                <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora13l" style="top: 123px; left: 0px;">
                </span>
                <!-- Arrow Right -->
                <span u="arrowright" class="jssora13r" style="top: 123px; right: 5px;">
                </span>
            </div>
```

Each slider has own id I create instances of this sliders like that:

```
$('.slider-left').each(function(i){
                jssor_slider_left[i] = new $JssorSlider$("slider"+i, options1);
            });
```

And my question is how to get `data-id` of active slide in each slider? I tried with:

```
for(j = 0; j < jssor_slider_left.length; j++){
                jssor_slider_left[j].$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, function SlideParkEventHandler(slideIndex, fromIndex){
                    var actual = $('.slides2').find("[data-id='"+slideIndex+"']").find('img');

                });
            }
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem may be with line

```
var actual = $('.slides2').find("[data-id='"+slideIndex+"']").find('img');
```

You want active image for single instance of the slider, right? But `$('.slides2')` returns all elements with class `slides2` (there are two in example markup, one for each slider instance). You want exactly one element, for current slider, so start with getting it.

```
var actual = $('#slider' + j).find('.slides2').find('[data-id="' + slideIndex + '"]').find('img');
```

You can even join CSS selectors and make the code shorter and more effective

```
var actual = $('#slider' + j + ' .slides2 [data-id="' + slideIndex + '"] img');
```

PS.

As far as I know polish language, it's "powierzchnia", not "powieszchnia" :D

Comment: Hmm, something went wrong because when I console.log(actual) it returns only sliders2 but I dont have this slider in my html markup.